# how to create Circular layout like this

Tags: actionscript-3, blackberry-playbook

[image]

How can i create circular scrollable layout .

I tried to add all icons in Group & than tried to rotate it , but no success because of jadgy edges.

I tried to rotate an image & according to this image rotation , i tried to set positions of icons.

Is there any other alternative to perfectly do it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the circle and its icons in a movieclip and make sure its registrationpoint matches the center of the circle. You can then rotate that movieclip. To avoid aliasing you can enable 'allow smoothing' in the properties of your bitmaps. For vectors you can enable hinting. Also to avoid aliasing it's generally a good idea to place objects on integer coordinates. So rounding the x,y coordinates of the movieclip and its contents (looping through them after rotating) might help too.